# Issues with Jquery timepicker change event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am having an issue getting jquery timepicker change event to trigger.  I need to update a field immediately after selecting a time.  Here is the code thus far

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Deploment Management</title>

        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/tabs.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/style.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.4/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery-1.6.1.min.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.easyui.min.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.4/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>

        <script>
            $(function(){
                $('#time').timepicker({
                    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
                    interval: 15,
                    dynamic: true,
                    dropdown: true,
                    scrollbar: true
                });

                $('#time').on('change', function() {
                    var x = document.getElementByName("time").value;
                    document.getElementById('d_time').value = "Maintenance Tonight - " +x;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="right">Scheduled Time:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="time" class="full" id="time" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="right">Email Subject:</td>
                <script>
                    function subject() {
                        if (document.getElementById('default').checked) {
                            document.getElementById('default_subject').style.display = 'block';
                            document.getElementById('custom_subject').style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        else if (document.getElementById('custom').checked) {
                            document.getElementById('custom_subject').style.display = 'block';
                            document.getElementById('default_subject').style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:subject();" id="default" name="radio" checked value="default">Default Subject
                    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:subject();" id="custom" name="radio" value="custom">Custom Subject
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>
                <div id="subject_field">
                    <div id="default_subject" style="display:block" name="default">
                        <input name="default" id="d_time" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="custom_subject" style="display:none" name="custom">
                        <input name="custom" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is abbreviated code but it should still do what I am trying to get it to do.  What I need it to do is on a time select the inpute with the ID d_time should update the default value as described in the above function but for some reason I can't get it to trigger.  Before I was using a select option for the time and it was working fine, this method I am clueless.

I don't use javascript or jquery often, a little help would be appreciated.  I read the documentation on the change event but it didn't really help.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can trigger your action thanks to the "changeTime" event of timepicker.js ([doc](http://jonthornton.github.io/jquery-timepicker/)). Btw, your timepicker.js version was old.
So you can try this :

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Deploment Management</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.6/jquery.timepicker.css">
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-timepicker/1.8.6/jquery.timepicker.js"></script>
        <script>
            $('document').ready(function(){
                $('#time').timepicker();
                $('#time').on('changeTime', function() {
                    var x = $("#time").val();
                    $('#d_time').val("Maintenance Tonight - " +x);
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td class="right">Scheduled Time:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="time" class="full" id="time" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="right">Email Subject:</td>
                <script>
                    function subject() {
                        if ($('#default').is(':checked')) {
                            $('#default_subject').css('display','block');
                            $('#custom_subject').css('display','none');
                        }
                        else if ($('#custom').is(':checked')) {
                            $('#custom_subject').css('display','block');
                            $('#default_subject').css('display','none');
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onclick="subject();" id="default" name="radio" checked value="default">Default Subject
                    <input type="radio" onclick="subject();" id="custom" name="radio" value="custom">Custom Subject
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>
                <div id="subject_field">
                    <div id="default_subject" style="display:block" name="default">
                        <input name="default" id="d_time" value="default" readonly="readonly"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="custom_subject" style="display:none" name="custom">
                        <input name="custom" type="text" value="custom"/>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: adding the updated library as you mentioned actually fixed the issue, now I just need it to pop up properly (it's popping up and off the screen) and use the formatting options.  I should be able to find this information.  Thank you

Answer (score 0):

put the on change function on a document ready

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $('#time').on('change', function() {
    var x = document.getElementByName("time").value;
    document.getElementById('d_time').value = "Maintenance Tonight - " +x;
  });
}
```

the thing is that the element is not created in the time you fire the functon so you need to wait untill the document is ready or put this function at the end of the document.

Comment: still doesn't fire

Comment: Put an alert in the event. Are yu sure the input have that id? Just leave an alert inside the event to be sure

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(function(){
                $('#time').timepicker({
                    timeFormat: 'h:mm p',
                    interval: 15,
                    dynamic: true,
                    dropdown: true,
                    scrollbar: true
                });

                $('#time').on('change', function() {
                    var x = document.getElementsByName("time")[0].value;
                    document.getElementById('d_time').value = "Maintenance Tonight - " +x;
                });
            });
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.4/jquery.timepicker.min.css">
        <link href="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/vader/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet">

       
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/timepicker/1.3.4/jquery.timepicker.min.js"></script>


<table>
            <tr>
                <td class="right">Scheduled Time:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="time" class="full" id="time" />
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="right">Email Subject:</td>
                <script>
                    function subject() {
                        if (document.getElementById('default').checked) {
                            document.getElementById('default_subject').style.display = 'block';
                            document.getElementById('custom_subject').style.display = 'none';
                        }
                        else if (document.getElementById('custom').checked) {
                            document.getElementById('custom_subject').style.display = 'block';
                            document.getElementById('default_subject').style.display = 'none';
                        }
                    }
                </script>
                <td>
                    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:subject();" id="default" name="radio" checked value="default">Default Subject
                    <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:subject();" id="custom" name="radio" value="custom">Custom Subject
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td/>
            <td>
                <div id="subject_field">
                    <div id="default_subject" style="display:block" name="default">
                        <input name="default" id="d_time" value="" readonly="readonly"/>
                    </div>
                    <div id="custom_subject" style="display:none" name="custom">
                        <input name="custom" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
```

try this

```
                $('#time').on('change', function() {
                    var x = document.getElementsByName("time")[0].value;
                    document.getElementById('d_time').value = "Maintenance Tonight - " +x;
                });
```

because getElementByName is not function use getElementsByName instead with index of first element

Comment: still doesn't fire off the event, could it be browser dependent?

Comment: here code is responded when we manually change time in input box but not in case when we select from list.